# How to Set Up Winform Textbox Field Focus so a User Can Go Through Them by Clicking Tab Button?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

UI is created in VS 2008. I'm using C# .... I need to let the user move/focus between text fields from top to bottom by clicking tab button. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set up the `TabIndex` property properly, so that it's sequential from top to bottom. Then it'll work automatically and you won't need any code to move around the focus.

So in other words, set the top `TextBox` `TabIndex` to 1, the next one you set to 2 etc and then one at the bottom will have the highest number (of the textboxes, you probably want to have even higher indexes for any OK buttons and similar so that the user can jump to them after editing all the textboxes).

You can find more info about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx

Answer (score 3):

On the Layout toolbar (will normally show up if you're in Design View) click on the buttom on the most right (it's called tab order).

Now on every element on your designer will come up a little box with a number. Just click all your elements in the order you like and they will automatically be re-ordered.

If you like to do it manually, just take ho1 advice and change the property manually.

Comment: Plus 1 for buttom. :)