# How to detect tab key pressing in C#?

Tags: c#, tabs, key, keypress

I want to detect when tab key is pressed in a textBox and focus the next textbox in the panel.

I have tried out keyPressed method and keyDown method. But when I run the program and debug those methods are not calling when the tab key is pressed.
Here is my code.

```
private void textBoxName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        textBoxUsername.Focus();
    }
}

private void textBoxName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Tab)
    {
        textBoxUsername.Focus();
    }
}
```

Please correct me.Thank you.

Comment: NOOO!!! Don't do it that way! Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942617/how-to-set-up-winform-textbox-field-focus-so-a-user-can-go-through-them-by-clicki/2942756#2942756

Comment: Did you see <https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914976/10205407>?
Credits: @Reza Aghaei

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to the properties of text box and assign correct order of tabindex

Comment: This answer does not answer what the OP ask. This is one of those hard situations where we have to answer what they asked or what is better.

Answer (score 10):

Why do you need that complication at all? WinForms does it for you automatically. You just need to set the correct tab order.

Comment: how do I put the correct tab order?
It's automatically placing in the wrong order that's why I wanted to do it manually.

Comment: Use the TabIndex property on the control. You can set this programmatically or you can use View -> Tab Order in the designer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use tabOrder instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want the "leave" event. I just threw this into the default C# WinForms application:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /* 
              ... misc housekeeping ... 
        */

        private void OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "left field 1";
        }

        private void OnLeave2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "left field 2";
        }
    }
}
```

It works as you would expect. Obviously you can do anything you want in the `Leave()` handler, including forcing the focus elsewhere, but be careful not to confuse the user...

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the [ProcessCmdKey method like this](http://amsakanna.blogspot.com/2008/09/catching-arrow-keys-in-vb-net.html)

Answer (score 0):

If textBoxName has a focus while pressing the TAB Key , then only the "KeyDown" event triggers.
You just need to set the correct tab order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with the text boxes inside a Panel, setting the correct tab index should do the job perfectly. But, if you are dealing with other text box from other Panel say:

panel1 has textbox1

panel2 has textbox2

panel3 has textbox3

Here's what you need to do:

1. Set the `TabStop = False` `property` of all the textboxes. By default, this is set to True.
2. Set the correct `TabIndex` for each panel, e.g.

   `panel1 TabIndex = 0;
   panel2 TabIndex = 1;
   panel3 TabIndex = 2;`
3. Then try this code

   `private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
           if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Tab))
              this.textBox3.Focus();
   }`