# Detect the Tab Key Press in TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am trying to detect the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press in a `TextBox`.
I know that the Tab key does not trigger the `KeyDown`, `KeyUp` or the `KeyPress` events. I found: Detecting the Tab Key in Windows Forms of BlackWasp in the internet.
They suggest to override the ProcessCmdKey, which I did, but it does not get triggered either.
Is there a reliable way to detect the Tab Key press?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{

    bool baseResult = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    if (keyData == Keys.Tab && textBox_AllUserInput.Focused)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tab key pressed.");
        return true;
    }
    if (keyData == (Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift) && textBox_AllUserInput.Focused)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Shift-Tab key pressed.");
        return true;
    }

    return baseResult;
}
```

According to Cody Gray's suggestion, I changed the code as follows:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab && textBox_AllUserInput.Focused)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tab key pressed.");        }
        if (keyData == (Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift) && textBox_AllUserInput.Focused)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Shift-Tab key pressed.");        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

The problem is that it does not capture the Tab key press.

Comment: Yes, ProcessCmdKey() is very reliable.  Nobody can tell how you fumbled it.

Comment: My code is: protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            bool baseResult = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            if (keyData == Keys.Tab && textBox_AllUserInput.Focused)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tab key pressed.");
                return true;
            }
          
            return baseResult;
        }  I tried all the 3 answers and none works.

Comment: Don't call the base implementation if you're going to override it. Move `base.ProcessCmdKey(...)` to the end of the function.

Comment: When you want to handle `Tab` key for a `TextBox`  you can simply handle [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) event and surely you don't need to override `ProcessCmdKey` and check what is the focused control!

Comment: Cody Gray,  I am sorry but I am not that versed in C# yet.  I do not know how to:  Subclass TextBox and override IsInputKey.

Answer (score 32):

Some key presses, such as the <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and arrow keys, are typically ignored by some controls because they are not considered input key presses.

You can handle [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of your control to handle those key strokes and set them as input key.

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Tab)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tab");
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Shift + Tab");
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a hack. The *actual* place to handle those key strokes is in the control itself. Subclass TextBox and override IsInputKey.

Comment: @CodyGray It's documented. Read the [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) section in documentation.  When you can handle a `Tab` key this way why do you need to subclass.

Comment: Sure, it is a documented hack. :-) Doesn't make it any less of a hack. There are lots of reasons to prefer subclassing, encapsulation, separation of concerns, and good design being chief among them. Reusability is another compelling concern. A subclass of TextBox would take maybe 3-4 more lines than this code, it's hardly a big effort.

Comment: @CodyGray All that concepts are good things, separation of concerns, encapsulation, etc. But handling a Tab character is not a good reason to subclass a control specially in the case that the OP wants to handle that key for a certain `TextBox` control and run a logic after that. It can be handled simply using events :)

Comment: Well, I disagree. The fact he is wanting to run specific logic afterwards is even more reason to subclass as far as I'm concerned. I'm not sure why you see subclassing as something undesirable to be avoided whenever possible. Anyway, you don't have to bend over backwards to please me, I didn't downvote this answer.

Comment: @CodyGray  *The fact he is wanting to run specific logic afterwards is even more reason to subclass as far as I'm concerned.* Suppose the OP wants to run a method ,F ,which is written in his form class, how should he run that method after he overrides `ProcessCmdKey` in his inherited `TextBox`? And of course,  It's just a technical discussion and will be useful for the OP and future readers :)

Comment: Cody Gray, I am sorry but I am not that versed in C# yet. I do not know how to: Subclass TextBox and override IsInputKey.

Comment: @user2102327 very old question, but I wonder if you could verify the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to determine when TAB Key is pressed:

```
 private void input_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    { 
        // Check here tab press or not
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
           // our code here
        }

        // Check for the Shift Key as well
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
           
        }
    }
```